# XSD restricting numbers in a string type pattern

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to restrict a string type attribute with a pattern. The attribute looks like this:

```
text(x,y,z)
for 0 <= x,y,z <= 255
```

So the 3 numbers inside the parenthesis must be restrictet to maximum values of 255.

Valid example:

```
text(24,0,255)
```

Invalid example:

```
text(15,635,5)
```

I tried already this, but it doesn't work:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="text\([0-255],[0-255],[0-255]\)"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Then i thought of doing something like this:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="text\(1?[0-9][0-9],1?[0-9][0-9],1?[0-9][0-9]\)|text\(2[0-4][0-9],1?[0-9][0-9],1?[0-9][0-9]\)|text\(25[0-5],1?[0-9][0-9],1?[0-9][0-9]\)|..."/>
</xs:restriction>
```

But as there are 3 possiblities for each of the 3 numbers, there would be 27 combinations.

Is there any other possibility to restrict numbers to maximum and minimum values in a string type than restricting each digit and combine all possibilities with an "or"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 regular expressions are the only solution available. It gets pretty nasty, as you've found, but it can be done. One neat trick that I have seen is to build reusable regex fragments using entity references:

```
<!ENTITY n255 "[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]">

<xs:pattern value="text\(&n255;,&n255;,&n255;\)"/>
```

I think I also came across a tool that automates the production of a regex to match integers in a given range, but I don't recall where.

In XSD 1.1 it might be better to combine a regex with an assertion:

```
<xs:pattern value="text\([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+)"/>
<xs:assertion test="every $t in tokenize(substring-before(substring-after($value, '('), ')'), ',') satisfies (number($t) ge 0 and number($t) le 255)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I have to use XSD 1.0, but your first solution works well and is much nicer than mine. 
One more question: if leading zeros are allowed for the numbers, is then the following possible to make it shorter: "1?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]" ?

Comment: Sure. It seems a bit odd to me to allow 06 but not 006, but that's up to you.